# Send various types of list in this same method

Tags: c#, dynamic

Here is my code:

```
var res = PrepareData(null);                //Prepare Data Returns a Tuple if two list assigned below.
List<Model.CameraSetting> lstCS = res.Item1; //List 1
List<ValidObjectsCameraSetting> lstVOCS = res.Item2; // List 2
if (isCSV)
{
       DataTable dtCameraSettings = ImportExportReportHelper.ConvertListToDataTable(lstCS);
       DataTable dtValidObjectCameraSetting = ImportExportReportHelper.ConvertListToDataTable(lstVOCS);
 }
```

Here is my

`public static DataTable ConvertListToDataTable(List<dynamic> list){
//Do Something
}`

method. How can I send any type of object here and do things with that. (What I will do is configured).

**I just want to send various types of list in this same method.**

Comment: Perhaps you could make it generic: `public static DataTable ConvertListToDataTable<T>(List<T> list)...`

Comment: Could you include some more details about what you will be doing inside your `ConvertListToDataTable` method? How do you plan to do the conversion, using reflection or something else?

Comment: Yes, I hope so. But wonder how?

Comment: @JackA. yes, I will use reflection, if I atleast get a List<object>.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could make it [generic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx):

```
public static DataTable ConvertListToDataTable<T>(List<T> list)
{
    Type listType = typeof(T);
    if(listType == typeof(CameraSetting))
    {
        //...
    }
    else if(listType == typeof(OtherThing))
    {
        //...
    }
    else  // if not everything is allowed
        throw new NotSupportedException(listType.ToString() + " is not supported in ConvertListToDataTable");
}
```

Comment: This approach is a violation of the Open Closed Principle: http://www.oodesign.com/open-close-principle.html. It will have to be modified every time you add a new type.

Comment: @JackA.: i just wanted to show how OP can use the type of T to differentiate between them if he needs it. Obviously it's not required at all since OP is using reflection anyway and all types are allowed. Then i could remove the entire method body. But i leave it as it is to help future readers.

Comment: @JackA. @TimSchmelter I have got the object type with reflection and then created datatable columns with the objects `propertyinfoes`. Then I populate the rows with list objects value, by getting each objects type(using reflection) and comparing the property name with data column name. As I have 100 of these types of table, so I decided to make a generic method which will get generic list and give a datatable. Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

**Using Non-Generics and Reflection**

If you are going to use reflection on the items in the list (and the items are not value types), there is no particular reason to use a generic list type. I would also recommend using an interface rather than a specific type. For example:

```
public static DataTable ConvertListToDataTable(IEnumerable list){
    foreach (object item in list)
    {
        //Do Something
    }
}
```

If you need the number of items in the list, you can use `ICollection` instead of `IEnumerable`:

```
public static DataTable ConvertListToDataTable(ICollection list){
    if (list.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (object item in list)
        {
            //Do Something
        }
    }
}
```

Both of these interfaces are implemented by the generic `List<>` class, so you can pass your original lists to the function with no mapping required.

**Using Generics**

There are benefits to using generics, especially type safety. When using generics, there is usually some kind of commonality between the types used for the type parameters. This is enforced using the `where` type constraint.

In this particular case, your method is converting items in a collection to rows in a data table. The commonality between the item types is that they are convertible to a data row. This could be defined using an interface, like so:

```
public interface IDataRowConvertible
{
}

public class CameraSettings : IDataRowConvertible
{
}

public static DataTable ConvertListToDataTable<T>(IEnumerable<T> list) where T : IDataRowConvertible
{
    // Do something
}
```

Another thing to consider is this: reflection can be tricky to get right. You may eventually run into situations where your generic reflection-based solution does not do what you want it to do. For example, say you add a property to one of your classes that you do not want to be included in the data row. Using an interface can solve both of these issues.

Let's change the interface to this:

```
public interface IDataRowConvertible
{
    void DefineColumns(DataColumnCollection columns);
    void WriteToRow(DataRow row);
}
```

You are now making the items responsible for defining what goes in the data table, and your conversion function becomes truly generic:

```
public static DataTable ConvertListToDataTable<T>(ICollection<T> list) where T: IDataRowConvertible
{
    if (list.Count > 0)
    {
        var table = new DataTable();
        list.First().DefineColumns(table.Columns);
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            var row = table.NewRow();
            item.WriteToRow(row);
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        return table;
    }
    return null;
}
```

The biggest downside to this is that all of your item classes now need to implement the two interface methods. However, you can create a reflection-based utility to make them easier to implement:

```
public void DefineColumns(DataColumnCollection columns)
{
    ReflectionUtil.DefineColumns(this, columns);
}

public void WriteToRow(DataRow row)
{
    ReflectionUtil.WriteToRow(this, row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make an mutual interface for both classes for example `ICameraSettings`, so you don't need to cast an objects inside the method and then change your lists to

```
List<ICameraSettings> lstCS;
List<ICameraSettings> lstVOCS;
```

or you can use [generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx).

```
public static DataTable ConvertListToDataTable<T>(List<T> list) where T:ICameraSettings
```

If you don't need to work with specific type you can use ICollection

```
 public static DataTable ConvertListToDataTable(ICollection list)
```

But if you have different logic for different types inside the method, probably you need to use [parameter overloading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms229029(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I would create and interface and then both classes implement it, doing that you could make a list of that type of interface.

edit. someone answered while i was typing sorry